# What is the actual mechanism behind ip tracking to your country of origin?

Tags: http, tcp, dns, ip-geolocation

When one wants to access say, hulu or amazon or pandora from another country, one can either use a dns unblocking service or a vpn service.

I "get" how a vpn service would work - it just routes all your traffic through a server farm in another country, so any checks on where you are are done against the server farm.

However, dns unblocking seems to just target the initial dns request, not the subsequent data streamed.

Assuming that streaming data etc works over http via tcp, then shouldn't the initial "fix" that dns unblocking does become undone the moment the ack is sent from the client?

Answer (score 0):

The IP address are allocated on a regional basis, so the different regional internet groups get allotted slots and they provide them to their local users. Under this assumption you can create a regional map for each IP. As the information on how the subdivision is known and again different IPs are assigned by ISPs to a specific region the further division is possible to a city level for large cities or a region for sparsely populated areas.